# how to write a function if I don't know number of parametrs (JS, Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I want to write a function which returns me formatted string. I wrote a random function "pickRandom" do I get always one random string from the array.

My example data:

```
const arr = ['Hi %s', '%s nice to seee you'];
```

For this example is easy to write a function:

```
const randomOutput = (arrayToChange, variable) => {
  const randomString = pickRandom(arrayToChange);

  return util.format(randomString, variable);
};
```

but how to modify my function that it works with multiple and no parametrs too. Is it possible? One function for every case?

I would like that it works:

```
const arr = ['Hi %s', '%s nice to seee you'];
const arr = ['Hi', 'Hi you'];
const moreP= ['Hi %s, you are %d years old', '%s, your age %d'];
```

So in that case it wont work:

```
randomOutput(moreP, "Anna", 19);
```

Comment: It should work for each value of arr you indicated. What is the actual problem ?

Comment: but not for this case Hi %s, you are %d years old', '%s, your age %d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use arguments spread syntax

```
const randomOutput = (arrayToChange, ...variables) => {
  const randomString = pickRandom(arrayToChange);

  return util.format(randomString, ...variables);
}
```